# Listview loadmore after completion goes back to the beginning of the list and notify data set changed does not work for button like counter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a listview with items where I can like and comment, after liking the count increases to let say 1, but if I scroll down and come back to the post I liked the like counter resets back to 0 like what was loaded from the server.

Secondly, I implemented load more button, but as soon as the loading more is done its goes back to the beginning of the listview instead of continuing from where i pressed the load more button. The problem occurs in the fragment part I implement the same load more logic with Activity and it worked fine.

```
public class ListViewAdapter_Post extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter_Post(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView usernameTV;
    TextView timeTV;
    TextView postTV;
    TextView schyrTV;

    ImageView postImg;
    ImageView profilePicImg;

    ImageButton commentBtn;
    ImageButton reportBtn;

    ImageButton likeBtn;

    TextView likesCount;
    TextView likestxt;
    TextView commentCount;
}

ViewHolder holder;
String username;
String reg_id;

String myyear;

public View getView(final int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {
    itemView = null;

    if (itemView == null) {


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_home, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.usernameTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_username);
        holder.timeTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_post_time);
        holder.postTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_post_text);
        holder.schyrTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_schoolyear);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.profilePicImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_profile_picture);
        holder.postImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_post_image);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.commentBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_comment_btn);
        holder.reportBtn= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_report_btn);

        holder.likesCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likesCount);
        holder.likestxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likestxt);
        holder.commentCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentCount);

        holder.likeBtn= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_like_btn);

    }

    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }


    holder.postImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    reg_id = resultp.get(Fragment_home.POST_REG_ID);

    String empty_image = resultp.get(Fragment_home.POST_PHOTO).toString();

    if(empty_image.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.dentymz.com/appx/dtbcknd/posts/")){

        holder.postImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //   Toast.makeText(context,"Post contains no pic",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else{
        holder.postImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //   Toast.makeText(context,"Post contains no pic",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Picasso.with(context).load(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_PHOTO)).placeholder(R.drawable.default_back_ash).fit().centerCrop().error(R.drawable.default_back_ash)
                .into(holder.postImg);
    }



    Picasso.with(context).load(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_PROFILE_PIC)).placeholder(R.drawable.default_back_ash).fit().centerCrop().error(R.drawable.default_back_ash)
            .into(holder.profilePicImg);



    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    holder.usernameTV.setText(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_USERNAME));
    holder.timeTV.setText(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_TIME));
   // holder.postTV.setText(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_TEXT));

    holder.postTV.setText(AndroidEmoji.ensure(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_TEXT), context));

    holder.schyrTV.setText(schyr);

    holder.likesCount.setText(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_LIKES_COUNT));
    holder.commentCount.setText(resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_COMMENTS_COUNT)+" Comments");

    DatabaseHandler db = DatabaseHandler.getDatabaseHandler(context);
    UserFunctions  userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(context);
    // user already logged in show dash board
    username = db.getUsername();

    if(resultp.get(Fragment_home.POST_LIKED_BY).toString().equals(username)){

        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp1);
        holder.likeBtn.setTag("liked");

    }

    else if(!resultp.get(Fragment_home.POST_LIKED_BY).toString().equals(username)){

        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp);
        holder.likeBtn.setTag("unliked");

    }

    else {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Error Occured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    final Intent user_profile = new Intent(context, MainProfile.class);
    final Intent main_profile = new Intent(context, MyProfile.class);




    holder.likeBtn.setTag(holder);
    holder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                resultp = data.get(position);

                if (holder.likeBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp).getConstantState())) {
                    resultp = data.get(position);

                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {


                        String number = holder.likesCount.getText().toString();
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        int nene = num + 1;
                        String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                        holder.likesCount.setText(str);

                        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp1);

                    }

                } else if (holder.likeBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp1).getConstantState())) {
                    resultp = data.get(position);

                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {


                        String number = holder.likesCount.getText().toString();
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        int nene = num - 1;
                        String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                        holder.likesCount.setText(str);

                        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp);

                    }
                }

            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                resultp = data.get(position);

                if (holder.likeBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.likeBtn.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp).getConstantState())) {
                    resultp = data.get(position);

                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {


                        String number = holder.likesCount.getText().toString();
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        int nene = num + 1;
                        String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                        holder.likesCount.setText(str);

                        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp1);

                    }

                } else if (holder.likeBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.likeBtn.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp1).getConstantState())) {
                    resultp = data.get(position);

                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {


                        String number = holder.likesCount.getText().toString();
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        int nene = num - 1;
                        String str = String.valueOf(nene);

                        holder.likesCount.setText(str);

                        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_24dp);

                    }
                }

            }


        }
    });




    final Intent post_comment = new Intent(context, Comments.class);
    holder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            post_comment.putExtra("id", resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_ID));
            post_comment.putExtra("username",resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_USERNAME));
            post_comment.putExtra("reg_id",resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_REG_ID));

            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(post_comment);



        }
    });




    holder.commentCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            post_comment.putExtra("id", resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_ID));
            post_comment.putExtra("username", resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_USERNAME));

            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(post_comment);


        }
    });


    final Intent likes = new Intent(context, Likes_post.class);
    holder.likesCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            likes.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            likes.putExtra("id",resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_ID));
            likes.putExtra("username", resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_USERNAME));

            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(likes);



        }
    });


    holder.likestxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            likes.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            likes.putExtra("id",resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_ID));
            likes.putExtra("username", resultp.get(Fragment_post.POST_USERNAME));

            post_comment.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(likes);



        }
    });


    return itemView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for load more issue, save position into a variable and then use listview.setselection(position) to go to the position before pressing load more button

i.e.:

```
int lastPosition = data.size();
loadMore();
listView.setSelection(lastPosition);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29